# How can I change the WordPress archive URL pattern?

Tags: wordpress, archive

I have an archives section in the right sidebar. You can check here. By default, the archive section gives the **/blog/2012/08/** URL pattern.

But I want the **/blog/archive/2012/08/** pattern without changing the Permalink pattern as the main posts using **blog/post_name**, and it should not be changed. How can I get this done?

I am new to WordPress.

Answer (score 3):

Tonight I come to this question with no answer. Although it's quite late to answer, but I try to answer it for future reference.
You can add following code snippet to `functions.php` file.

```
function change_archive_links() {
global $wp_rewrite;
// add 'archive'
$wp_rewrite->date_structure ='blog/archive/%year%/%monthnum%/';
}
add_action('init','change_archive_links');
```

Don't forget to flush WordPress rewrite rules after adding the snippet. To do that, go to WP Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks and press Save Changes button.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Iqbal. Its definitely useful for someone who is in need. I dont even remember how I have solved that 8 years before :)