# How do I exclude archive directories from a rewrite rule OR rewrite the archive path to include a custom category?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks

I am struggling with a solution to my problem with a recent wordpress site transition. My old wordpress site had /blog/%category%/%postname%/ as the permalink. With the new site we have changes that to: /news/%category%/%postname%/

I then made a Rewrite Rule to redirect all existing blog posts:
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) /news/executive-insights/$1 [R=301,L]

However, I didn't realize at the time that this also broke all archive URL paths.

Example:

https://www.example.com/blog/2022/04/29/ now redirects to a 404 page of:
https://www.example.com/news/executive-insights/2022/04/29/

1.) I either need a fancy way to exclude archive directory(2022,2021,2020, etc.) from the rewrite rule.
2.) Or I need a way to include /executive-insights/ as part of the archive URL path instead of: https://www.example.com/news/2022/04/29/

PS- Please don't tell me to update my custom permalink to include year/month/day that is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```html
//===========================================================
// START - Add /executive-insights/ into the archive url path
//===========================================================
function change_archive_links() {
global $wp_rewrite;
// add 'archive'
$wp_rewrite->date_structure ='news/executive-insights/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%';
}
add_action('init','change_archive_links');
//===========================================================
// END - Add /executive-insights/ into the archive url path
//===========================================================
```

Shout out: [How can I change the WordPress archive URL pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122373/how-can-i-change-the-wordpress-archive-url-pattern)